# QGIS On the fly reprojection issue

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

i'm having an issue with QGIS 2.14.3 (Windows 10). I've two layers:

- PostGIS table (EPSG:23030)
- Shapefile (EPSG:25830)

I setup on the fly transformation (23030) in QGIS, just for check, but both layers does not overlay.

However if I do same thing with another software (gvSIG or ArcGIS) it works fine.

Anyone knows what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the +towgs84 parameter. The 23030 layer is stored in a PostGIS 1.4.2 database and it hasn't +towgs84 in proj4text column spatial_ref_sys table:

```
+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs
```

Answer (score 0):

If the shift is around 100m it might be due to datum transformation as another reference ellipsoid is used in both. If this is the case you need the transformation parameters for ED 50 towards GRS80 in QGIS. The other programs might have this already and applying it therefore correctly.

You can also reproject on of them using the also installed grass-gis with v.proj as grass gis tend to have more transformations already delivered.